# Jquery autocomplete combobox adding title attributes on newly created lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm currently using Jquery autocomplete combobox to create some filters.

Functionality wise, it is all good.

But I'm having a issue where I would like to set "title" attributes each options that are newly created/filtered after typing key words on combobox.

[image]

Above image is showing the list of options with initial load. Which title attribute is conserved from initial option elements.

[image]

Above image is showing the list of options after I have newly typed keywords.

The reason why I need tittle is that I'm currently displaying URL of multiple sites and actual width given to combobox is never enough to display the full length of URL.

Thank you for reading my post and I hope to hear any solution or feedback.

Comment: can you show some code ?

Comment: [link](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox) Similar to this, except I have my own codes to assign a title attribute to each select options

Comment: After more googling, I found the solution. This [link] (http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-_renderItem) reference how to approach and this [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664964/jquery-autocomplete-renderitem) explains where most of people might fall on simple issue. (it's .data('ui-autocomplete')) I hope this helps other people like me.. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: Great!, do you know you can answer your own question, and mark it as the solution. !?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending time, I found the solution by myself.. 
(lots of people already spent time on this..)

If you are having same issue as I had, please have a look at comments on previous post.

I hope it helps.

Thank you all